# How to do a dynamic pulsating button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, transition, css-animations

I am trying to make my button pulsate from green to black and back in the an infinite loop. It is my first time working with @keyframes, I tried in CSS and worked perfectly, but doing it in javascript puzzles me a bit. How do I fix this and also I want this button to be infinitely pulsating through javascript since the button was dynamically created in javascript.

```
// create an input element
var frm = document.getElementById("result");
var submitBtn = document.createElement("input");
submitBtn.type = "submit";
submitBtn.value = "Confirm Purchase";
frm.appendChild(submitBtn);
submitBtn.style.animation = "pulse 5s infinite";

var cssAnimation = document.createElement('style');
 cssAnimation.type = 'text/css';
var rules = document.createTextNode('@keyframes pulse {'+
'from { background-color:green; }'+
 '80% { background-color:black; }'+
'90% { background-color:green; }'+
'to { background-color:back; }'+
'}');
cssAnimation.appendChild(rules);
//document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssAnimation);
submitBtn.appendChild(cssAnimation);
```

Comment: Provide your http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @AshishMishra http://jsfiddle.net/6m7uN/

Comment: You just want to add your `CSS animation` using javascript? right?

Comment: yes, correct! As you can see I already added it, but the animation isn't working.

Comment: On which browser you work?

Comment: @AshishMishra I'm working on firefox for now, will test other browsers as well.

Comment: yes, my fiddle is work on chrome..only for `Firefox` you have to replace `webkit` to `moz`

Comment: In `jsfiddle`,you have to select option under `Frameworks & Extensions` -> `inhead`,so your code placed at head of document,and whatever the function you call in 'html' it works..

Comment: ,you made a mistake on line 211 : See working :  http://jsfiddle.net/YX9q5/3/

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer,that is works correctly for you...So others can see that easily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assume* you worked in `chrome`

I see your given [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m7uN),And found some errors:

Here I use `-webkit`

If you create animation then you must have to use `-webkit-` for `chrome` or `safari`
and for others are `-o-` for `opera`, `-moz-` for `Mozilla` and for `IE` you can directly add or add `-ms-`.

Here what i find that ,
You use only '.animation' in JavaScript rather then , `.webkitAnimation` So your animation isn't work!

And Your code is not formatted well,As this is javascript ,So it Compile line by line,So you have to first append your dynamic `style tag` then apply your animation to html element !

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6m7uN/1/)

May this will help you...

Answer (score 3):

If you define the animation with CSS3 rules, then you can use Javascript to apply this style simply by setting the button's `className` attribute.

Here's an example:

## HTML

```
<p><button id="btn1">Buy Now!</button></p>
```

## CSS

Let's start by setting up a basic style for the button:

```
button {
    color:#696;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16pt;
    border:4px outset #070;
    border-radius:1em;
    background-color:#000;
    padding:0.3em 1em;
}
```

Now define an additional class with the flashing animation:

```
.clickplz {
    animation:btn 2s;
    -webkit-animation:btn 2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes btn  {
    0%   {color:#8c8; background-color:#000; text-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(255,255,144,0);}
    50%  {color:#fff; background-color:#0b0; text-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(255,255,144,0.75);}
    100% {color:#8c8; background-color:#000; text-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(255,255,144,0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes btn {
    0%   {color:#8c8; background-color:#000; text-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(255,255,144,0);}
    50%  {color:#fff; background-color:#0b0; text-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(255,255,144,0.75);}
    100% {color:#8c8; background-color:#000; text-shadow:0 0 9px rgba(255,255,144,0);}
}
```

## Javascript

Now all you need to do to start the button flashing is add the `clickplz` class to the button:

```
document.getElementById('btn1').className='clickplz';
```

▶ **[Here's a JSFiddle page containing all of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/sT7Su/1/)**

Comment: Nice animation, this is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a bunch! Do you mind telling me why my select options onload() doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/YX9q5/